# Does Entourage ever make reference to it taking place in a specific year?

Tags: chronology, entourage

I recently saw the Entourage movie after having been a fan of the TV show.

It was a little jarring because the movie is supposed to take place within a couple weeks of the end of the show, but there are references to things that have happened since then (The Avengers, iPhone 5s, etc.).

Afterwards I started thinking about if Entourage the show ever referenced any year specifically and I couldn't think of a time where they did. I had just always assumed that the current season was taking place in the year it was airing.

From a real world perspective it seems likely that they intended each season of the show to roughly take place in the year it was airing and the fact that the movie came out 4 years later didn't connect with the story they wanted to tell, so they just glazed over it. But from a purely in-show logic point of a view, could the show have been taking place slightly in the future the whole time (and they were just using old phones, etc.) which would allow it to realistically connect with the movie? Am I wrong and they do reference a specific year at some point? Or is it possible to put together a timeline of the show using birthdays, length of film shoots, etc.?

Comment: It's my understanding that *Entourage* took place in modern day (for example, season 6 aired in 2009 and had auditions for the *Melrose Place* reboot, also from 2009, so if anything it's slightly in the *past*) and that the film's timeline is simply [wonky](http://www.vulture.com/2015/06/wait-when-does-the-entourage-movie-take-place.html).

Comment: Hah, didn't notice @Walt already linked to the Vulture piece in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vulture wondered the same thing](http://www.vulture.com/2015/06/wait-when-does-the-entourage-movie-take-place.html) and came up with several possible explanations, one of which is this:

> **What if the Entourage finale didn't take place in 2011?**
>
> All along,
>   we've been assuming that when Entourage wrapped up in 2011, it was
>   also 2011 in the show's timeline. But what if, through the show's gaps
>   between seasons and intermittent flash-forwards, the final season of
>   Entourage actually ended up taking place ... in the future? Heck, the
>   two seasons of Rome took place over a period of 18 years; is it really
>   so impossible that Entourage could have covered 10 years in eight
>   seasons? (This theory, however, could be disproved by **examining the
>   last season of Entourage for 2011 specifics —at one point E says the
>   Chilean mining accident, which happened in 2010, was "like a year
>   ago,"** also when else would Johnny Galecki have been so prominent? —
>   but come on, who wants to re-watch the last season of Entourage?)

Comment: Both you and @Walt linked to this article and I really doubt there's a more thorough breakdown of the timeline, or a better discussion on possibilities, than the article provides